# Minus values Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have the below Oracle working fine however I want to calculate `Sum(manhours)-Leavetaken`

I am unsure if this is because some of values of `Leavetaken` are null so it's pulling back null if I try it as above. But if even `leavetaken` is null, I want just the full value of `sum(manhours)`

Here's  my current query:

```
select lsc.work_date, location,site, sum(manhours), Leavetaken
from location_site_capacity lsc
left outer join (
    select work_date, sum(manhours) as Leavetaken from location_site_capacity
    where break is not null
    group by work_date) A on A.work_date = lsc.work_Date
where lsc.work_date between '01/JUN/15' and '30/JUN/15'
group by  lsc.work_date, location,site, Leavetaken
order by lsc.work_Date,location
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce()` on `Leavetaken`, like this:

```
select ..., sum(manhours) - coalesce(Leavetaken, 0) as calc
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value.

Comment: seems perfect :) will run a few quick tests but looks exactly like what i need :) thanks so much! not aware of the 'coalesce' function will read into it for future knowledge